# How to argue this "standard elliptic estimates" for a convergence?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am estudying the paper: INEQUALITIES FOR SECOND-ORDER ELLIPTIC EQUATIONS WITH APPLICATIONS TO UNBOUNDED
DOMAINS I - H. BERESTYCKI, L. A. CAFFARELLI, AND L. NIRENBERG

At the page $482$, we have a function
$$z^j(x,y)=\frac{1}{\alpha^j}u(x,y),$$
with $\alpha^j\Rightarrow\infty$ and
$$\Delta z^j+\frac{1}{\alpha^j}g(\alpha^j z^j)+\frac{1}{\alpha^j}f(0)=0, \ \ \ \mbox{in} \ \ (-2,2)\times\overline\omega$$
The function $z^j$ satisfies
$$z^j\leq a, \ \ \ \mbox{in} \ \ (-2,2)\times\overline\omega,$$
where $\omega$ is a bounded domain. Then, by "standad elliptic estimates", $z^j$ converge uniformly in $[-1,1]\times\overline\omega$ to a function $\overline z$, which belongs to $C^{2,\gamma}$ there, for some $\gamma\in(0,1)$, and $\overline z$ satisfies:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\Delta\overline z+\overline g(\overline z)=0, & (-1,1)\times\omega,\\
\overline z=0, & (-1,1)\times\partial\omega.
\end{array}
$$
This page can be viewed in: http://books.google.com.br/books?id=iCH9EGj3YkEC&pg=PA468&lpg=PA467&ots=rRKiPZbFhr&dq=INEQUALITIES+FOR+SECOND-ORDER+ELLIPTIC+EQUATIONS+WITH+APPLICATIONS+TO+UNBOUNDED+DOMAINS+I&lr=&hl=pt-PT

I don't know to explain this convergence. Someone can help me? 
Thank You!

Comment: You should specifiy what all the terms are, which ones are functions, which are variables, etc.